# How to exclude subdomains from re-write rules in htaccess

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

In my htaccess file, I have the following code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

I'd like to make it so that if a subdomain is entered, it doesn't re-write it to www.sub.domain.com, but instead just sub.domain.com. I've played with this multiple times and can't seem to get it right. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Now it will redirect `domain.com` to `www.domain.com` but will skip `sub.domain.com`.